# How to control the dimension of an image during the upload with symfony2

Tags: image, forms, symfony, upload, dimension

i check in the doc and everywhere i could but i didn't find any solution.

So i have a form and i upload an image in this form. I would like an error message if user is submiting a too large image or a too tall one. I need to do this for a proper display for my image.

I would like if possible do this with @assert but i dont think it's possible so i can add a validation.yml file if it's needed but it has to be check on the client-side

Thx if you have any clue to do this !

Comment: Wait, are you aware that Symfony is a server side framework?, client side validation is done using js in this case. Anyway, you'll find the image assert right in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html#maxwidth

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer it's working fine but for exemple if i declare my form in a controller and write ->add('foo', 'integer'), the input gonna be check on server side ? hmmm i guess yes because when you're submitting you do a request. Alright it makes sense my bad ;) thx for your help !